# Load geojson in bigquery

Tags: json, load, google-bigquery, geojson

What is the best way to load the following geojson file in Google Big Query?

http://storage.googleapis.com/velibs/stations/test.json

I have a lot of json files like this (much bigger) on Google Storage, and I cannot download/modify/upload them all (it would take forever). Note that the file is not newline-delimited, so I guess it needs to be modified online.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step by step 2019:

If you get the error "Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: Nested arrays not allowed.", you might have a GeoJSON file.

Transform GeoJSON into new-line delimited JSON with `jq`, load as CSV into BigQuery:

```
jq -c .features[] \
  san_francisco_censustracts.json > sf_censustracts_201905.json

bq load --source_format=CSV \
  --quote='' --field_delimiter='|' \
  fh-bigquery:deleting.sf_censustracts_201905 \
  sf_censustracts_201905.json row
```

Parse the loaded file in BigQuery:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `fh-bigquery.uber_201905.sf_censustracts`
AS
SELECT FORMAT('%f,%f', ST_Y(centroid), ST_X(centroid)) lat_lon, *
FROM (
  SELECT *, ST_CENTROID(geometry) centroid
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(row, '$.properties.MOVEMENT_ID') AS INT64) movement_id
      , JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(row, '$.properties.DISPLAY_NAME') display_name
      , ST_GeogFromGeoJson(JSON_EXTRACT(row, '$.geometry')) geometry
    FROM `fh-bigquery.deleting.sf_censustracts_201905` 
  )
)
```

---

Alternative approaches:

- With ogr2ogr:

  - https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-load-geographic-data-like-zipcode-boundaries-into-bigquery-25e4be4391c8
  - https://medium.com/@mentin/loading-large-spatial-features-to-bigquery-geography-2f6ceb6796df
- With Node.js:

  - https://github.com/mentin/geoscripts/blob/master/geojson2bq/geojson2bqjson.js

Answer (score 2):

The bucket in the question no longer exists.... However five years later there is a new answer.
In July 2018, Google [announced](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/bridging-the-gap-between-data-and-insights) an alpha (now beta) of BigQuery GIS. 
The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/gis-data) highlight a limitation that

> BigQuery GIS supports only individual geometry objects in GeoJSON.
>   BigQuery GIS does not currently support GeoJSON feature objects,
>   feature collections, or the GeoJSON file format.

This means that any Feature of Feature Collection properties would need to be added to separate columns, with a geography column to hold the geojson geography.

In this [tutorial](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-load-geographic-data-like-zipcode-boundaries-into-bigquery-25e4be4391c8) by a Google trainer, polygons in a shape file are converted into geojson strings inside rows of a CSV file using [gdal](https://www.gdal.org/).

```
ogr2ogr -f csv -dialect sqlite -sql "select AsGeoJSON(geometry) AS geom, * from LAYER_NAME" output.csv inputfilename.shp
```

You want to end up with one column with the geometry content like this

```
{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[....]]}
```

Other columns may contain feature properties.

The CSV can then be imported to BQ. Then a query on the table can be viewed in [BigQuery Geo Viz](https://bigquerygeoviz.appspot.com/).  You need to tell it which column contains the geometry.